# How to make the product info column wider without changing image position?

Tags: magento2, layout, template

In Blank theme product pages the `product-info-main` class has the value `width:43%`. If this value is set to any number greater than 43, the product image moves to the bottom of the page.
I've tried changing the size image in the file `mytheme/etc/view.xml` but does not work. Even when I set the image size to 20px, it goes to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product Info Main at 43% floats right of Product Media (width: 57%). If you need a wider column for Product Info Main, just decrease the width of .product.media first, and then increase the width of .product-info-main to (100 - width of .product.media - any margins you add)

Example:

```
.page-layout-1column .product-info-main{width:60%}
.page-layout-1column .product.media{width:40%}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the product image is smaller, how can I make it bigger? I cant find the class properties related to the size of the image

Comment: Well, you reduced the size of the container that the image resides in, so it was bound to get smaller. Is it still filling up the container? You can use inspect element to find out the relevant classes.